# Net::IMAP::ByeResponseError: Too many commands before auth m18if18344299pag.70 in Rails 3 (Gmail API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just want to know the meaning of this unfamiliar error message displayed by a failed Resque job:

```
Xiruki-Tepe.local:30134 on GMAIL_TODAY at just now
Class
Jobs::Gmail::Today
Arguments
1
Exception
Net::IMAP::ByeResponseError
Error
Too many commands before auth m18if18344299pag.70
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Error raised upon a "BYE" response from the server, indicating that the client is not being allowed to login, or has been timed out due to inactivity.